# php for each loop inserting data twice not each row as intended

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have an associative php array that is created using the JSON decode function.

I am attempting to then insert this array row by row into my database.

The values are inserting but I am getting repeats of the last row.

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "config.php";


$gambatch =  $_POST["mydata"];
$myjson = json_decode($gambatch,true);
 foreach ($myjson as $row){
        //get the tweet details
        $name = $row[0];
        $points = $row[1];    
    }
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO testjson(named,points)
            VALUES ('".$name."','".$points."')";

 if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql1))
       {
           die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
       }
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo '<br><br><br><br><br><br>';
echo "data added";
```

The Json is from another page when dumped from php after json decode looks like this :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(6) "dddddd" [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(0) [6]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(7) "fffffff" [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(0) [6]=> int(0) } }
```

This is the full array but I am only trying to insert the first two values in each row) in the code above (eventually I want to insert all but I am kept it smaller while getting it to work).

This is also an array with just two entries it will eventually be dynamic and accept many more so the code needs to be flexible enough. I think I am nearly there?

I am getting no PHP errors the problem is the duplicate entries. It either replacing itself or I have a piece of looping code that I have not spotted.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Finally I will be using prepared statements - using this dangerous sql because it is easy to mock up

Comment: You are overwriting the `$name` and `$points` variable by each loop as you perform later (outside the loop)the sql query

Comment: this is more a codereview question (codereview.stackexchange.com), but you have `mysqli_query` twice in your code... (see lines 15 & 19) if you run the query twice - you will get 2 new rows in your table.

Comment: @Dekel This would not be a good question on Code Review, as the code does not work as intended. If the OP fixes the problem and then wants a review, they are welcome to post it on CR.

Comment: Hello @ Dekel. I have removed the extra statement and it has had the desired effect of not getting duplicates but I now only get 1 row not every row in the associative array going into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working after some further reading. I have added the prepared statement insert as well.

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$gambatch =  $_POST["mydata"];


$myjson = json_decode($gambatch,true);
$myLength= count($myjson);
//echo 'length is '.$myLength.'';
$query = $con->stmt_init();


for ($row = 0; $row <  $myLength; $row++) {
          $name = $myjson[$row][0];
       $points = $myjson[$row][1];
        //$sql1 = "INSERT INTO testjson(named,points)
       //     VALUES ('".$name."','".$points."')";
     $statement = $con->prepare( "INSERT INTO testjson (named,points)  VALUES (?,?) ");
     $statement->bind_param('si', $name, $points);
      $statement->execute();    


 }

//if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
  //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
//}

//echo '<br><br><br><br><br><br>';
//echo "data added";
//} 
//mysqli_close($con);
$statement->close();
```

I have left old insert as it may help with conversion down the line somewhere.

A for loop was required using the array row length as the upper bound. This was extracted using the count($yourArray). above is for two columns and potentially unlimited rows.

The only is issue I have with the code is I think it can be more efficient as I am performing multiple inserts with the execute inside the loop. If someone can solve that I will switch the answer.